# Can't access Webserver on port 80 outside LAN

Tags: linux, ubuntu, webserver

I have an old box which I am using as a webserver to host some apps. I recently moved to a new place and my webserver is now not allowing access via port 80. In my previous place with Shaw internet the webserver worked perfectly. My current place also with Shaw is not allowing port 80. All I did was plug the server in, forwarded the ports and ran sudo ifup eth0. I thought that would do it however I still can't get port 80 working. I have forwarded port 80/80 TCP and 20/20 TCP (this works) for static IP 192.168.0.20. My interfaces file looks like:

```
  auto lo
   iface lo inet loopback

   iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.20
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.0.1
    broadcast 192.168.0.255
    gateway 192.168.0.1
```

Running nmap on the server shows that port 80 is open and ifconfig returns the same inet addr as my interfaces file. Any ideas what I might be missing? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you have a static public IP? Is it possible you have a dynamic public IP instead? If so, there is no amount of port forwarding that will solve your problem.

Comment: When you "running nmap on the server", do you mean from the inside or from the outside? If you can run it from the outside, try ncat or telnet.

Comment: Are you sure your ISP does not filter the port? Or is that what you checked with nmap?

Comment: are you trying to access stuff on 192.168.0.20 from the outside world or are you talking about accessing content on your LAN over port 80 is not working?   I am assuming that you are referring to connections from the outside world, but all I see in your question is references to private IP address ranges.   Do you get any response at all when you try to access your web server from the outside world or does the connection just time out?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae - it is definitely a static IP.

Comment: @Krumelur - There is an option in the router configs to block port 80 or not and its turned off.

Comment: @Richie086 - I can access the server on port 80 internally with 192.168.0.20 but the connection times out when I try externally to my external IP.

Comment: I just tried to reach my external IP from a friends house and it worked. But when I try to reach it locally at my house the connection times out.

Comment: Well that's a start.  Why not just access it over 192.168 when you are at home and by its external when not?  That actually sounds like a horrible solution.  Do you have a DNS domain name that you could attach to your home connection?  Dynamic DNS?

Comment: I could add it to my vhosts to route it through 192.168

Answer (score 0):

> I just tried to reach my external IP from a friends house and it worked. But when I try to reach it locally at my house the connection times out.

Then your problem lies in your router not allowing [hairpinning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairpinning). The best explanation I have seen of this is [on the Mikrotik's wiki](http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Hairpin_NAT), which also contains an explanation of how to get around this problem, **if** you have access to your router and it allows you control of its firewall/NAT system. But this work-around has the defect that your Web server will see **all** connections as coming from your router, so that the usual control of the connecting IPs (for security or statitics reasons) will become impossible.

There are routers allowing hairpinning, a notable one being Infiniti's Edgemax; a Google search will allow you  to find some. Incidentally, this is one of the reasons why it is a bad idea (even apart from security) to develop Web sites on your own LAN, the alternative being renting a VPS.